# Azure role assignment throws Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

We are using powershell in devops release pipeline to Assign role to FuntionApp

using following script
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $env:funcId -RoleDefinitionName "" -Scope "${env:roleid}"

but getting following exception
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.
not much details in release pipeline logs

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing the powershell command in the pipeline I am assuming you are making use of the Service Principal.

The error is likely to occur if the SPN  does not have sufficient priveleges.

From my research - Az Commands make use of the Legacy AAD Graph.

Ensure you have the below permission is set up for the SPN :

**Directory.Read.All (AAD Graph)**

[image]